# How to prevent left "post" section from dropping off?

Tags: css

I've got an issue with my blog. When the browser window is narrowed down just so, the left part of the page (the "posts" area), drops. You can see it in action here:

http://www.itscodingtime.com/

Just drag the right-side of the browser to the left, narrowing the browser width, and it happens.

I can post the CSS if needed (let me know), but I've basically got one side of the page floated to the left and the other to the right. I think I need to use a clear (or maybe not) somewhere, but I'm not sure.

So, how can I keep the "posts" section from dropping off? I'm OK setting a min width across the whole page if that's what will keep it from happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
#wrap, #content-wrap{min-width:1018px;}
```

Of course, min-width is not supported in IE6. I'd add this to get around it:

```
<!--[if lte IE 6]><style type="text/css">#wrap, #content-wrap{width:1018px;}</style><![endif]-->
```

Comment: Cool... it works! Now, should I add the first code snippet to my style.css, and the second to my master page?