# IE6 bugs! side panel

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

My right side navigation is pushed down to the bottom on the page for some reason in IE6 but its only on my blog pages! Am I right in thinking its somthing to do with the sidepanels width?

http://bradburyembroidery.com/houses4cash/blog/

Comment: I asked a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182147/how-to-prevent-left-post-section-from-dropping-off The proposed answer worked quite well.

Comment: it might help to provide valid html, see the validator here: http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fbradburyembroidery.com%2Fhouses4cash%2Fblog%2F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the left margin on the unordered lists inside #side to be 0. This is because IE and other browsers have different ways they indent lists, most browsers use padding and IE uses margin.

You had overridden the browser defaults for other browsers but not for IE which you also need to do. These extra margins were forcing the side bar to be bigger than it should have been and because it was floated it dropped below the content.

```
#side2 ul {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

That will fix it.

Comment: Thanks! Silly little things like that take me years to figue out!!!

Answer (score 1):

Float the `<div id="sidePanel">` element to the left, not to the right.

I believe that will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your `#side2` lists.  You have `<li>`s that are not in a `<ul>`

```
<ul>
    <!-- Author information is disabled per default. Uncomment and fill in your details if you want to use it.
    <li><h2>Author</h2>
    <p>A little something about you, the author. Nothing lengthy, just an overview.</p>
    </li>
    -->
    <li>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul role="navigation">
    <li class="pagenav"><h2>Pages</h2><ul><li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="http://www.housesforcashuk.co.uk/blog/about/" title="About">About</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-6"><a href="http://www.housesforcashuk.co.uk/blog/complaints-procedure/" title="Complaints Procedure">Complaints Procedure</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><h2>Archives</h2>
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.housesforcashuk.co.uk/blog/2009/07/" title="July 2009">July 2009</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.housesforcashuk.co.uk/blog/2009/06/" title="June 2009">June 2009</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li class="categories"><h2>Categories</h2>
<ul>    
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-1"><a href="http://www.housesforcashuk.co.uk/blog/category/uncategorized/" title="View all posts filed under Uncategorized">Uncategorized</a> (8)
    </li>
</ul>
</li>       
</ul>
<ul>

</ul>
```